# How to say "I don't know you well"

Tags: translation, politeness, spoken-language

I'm trying to tell someone the reason I don't want to do something is because i barely know them. I'm not even sure if the verb I'm suppose to be using is 知る。I feel that might be really rude to say to someone. 
I searched around and the only word I can find that might work is なじむ(馴染む)。
I also don't know if I should use their name like 
Example :
まだアリサさんになじまない = I'm not familiar with Alyssa yet.

Comment: Straight translation questions are off-topic here, but I feel like there's more to this question than just that.  You're asking about politeness as well.  If you can edit your question to include a translation attempt, then people would be able to comment on whether the phrase you've come up with is rude or not, or possibly suggest alternatives.

Comment: I disagree. The translation she's asking help for isn't something "where a simple dictionary search combined with understanding the basics of Japanese sentence construction would suffice". 
Furthermore,she did research prior to asking that question, which shows her effort in trying to understand it herself.
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

なじむ is rarely used for a person, so まだアリサさんになじまない is unnatural.

I think 知る、親しくなる、仲良くなる are better like ～さんをよく知らない、～さんと親しくなっていない、～さんと仲良くなっていない.

Comment: I think these options also convey a positive image that you will eventually become familiar with them later on. Also, if the person you barely know was someone you recently met, maybe 出会ったばかりの人 could also be used.

Comment: Yes, because the OP took care the rudeness.